# Having Trouble Drawing With An ArrayList

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jcomponent

I am having a little bit of trouble drawing components from an ArrayList I have created. If I screw around with it, I can either get the first element or the second element and if I am lucky, neither, to show up!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FaceShortCode {
ArrayList<CreateCircles> faceCircles = new ArrayList<CreateCircles>();

public FaceShortCode() {
    JFrame main = new JFrame();
    main.setTitle("Face Frame");
    main.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setVisible(true);

    Container c = main.getContentPane();
    // c.setLayout(null);

    faceCircles.add(0, new CreateCircles(100, 50, 400, 350, Color.red));
    faceCircles.add(1, new CreateCircles(200, 100, 65, 65, Color.black));
    c.add(faceCircles.get(0));
    c.add(faceCircles.get(1));

}

class CreateCircles extends JComponent {
    double x, y, width, height;
    Color myColor;

    public CreateCircles(double x, double y, double width, double height,
            Color myColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.myColor = myColor;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
        g2.setColor(myColor);
        g2.fill(circle);

    }
}

static class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FaceShortCode();
    }
}
```

}

I have tried throwing in a main.repaint() after every addition to the Container c,tried a repaint() in my painting method but nothing seems to be working. Is there any were else to put a repaint() that I am just missing?

Comment: The layout manager doesn't know where to put the components that are added to the container. Is only the component that is added last showing?  That's probalby because the last add replaced the earlier one.  Decide how you want the layout to look and chose a layout manager that will give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your logic before you `setVisible()` or else your frame will become visible before the logic is performed.

```
public FaceShortCode() {

    Container c = main.getContentPane();
    // c.setLayout(null);

    faceCircles.add(0, new CreateCircles(100, 50, 400, 350, Color.red));
    faceCircles.add(1, new CreateCircles(200, 100, 65, 65, Color.black));
    c.add(faceCircles.get(0));
    c.add(faceCircles.get(1));

    JFrame main = new JFrame();

    main.setTitle("Face Frame");
    main.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setVisible(true);
}
```

Consider making `FaceShortCode` extends `JFrame`.

```
public class FaceShortCode extends JFrame {
    private ArrayList<CreateCircles> faceCircles = new ArrayList<CreateCircles>();

    public FaceShortCode {
        setLayout(new Girdlayout(1, 2));

        faceCircles.add(0, new CreateCircles(100, 50, 400, 350, Color.red));
        faceCircles.add(1, new CreateCircles(200, 100, 65, 65, Color.black));

        add(faceCircles.get(0));
        add(faceCircles.get(1))

        setTitle("Face Frame");
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Consider making FaceShortCode extends JFrame. It's better practice` - no it isn't. There is no need to extend a JFrame since you haven't changed any of the properties of the frame. Look at the examples in the Swing tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is a bit confusing. There is no need for an ArrayList. When you use components you can just add the components directly to the panel. Normally you would only use an ArrayList when you are doing custom painting by painting Objects that are not components, for example when you want to paint a Shape. For an example of this approach take a look at [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

When using components, a component needs a size and location in order to be painted automatically by Swing. Normally you would let a layout manager determine these properties. In your case you are doing random placement of your components so you would need to use a null layout and then set the size/location of each component.

So what you need to do is change how you paint your custom component. All painting should be done at location (0, 0) of your component. Then you would set the location of the component to be the x/y value. This means the component will be painted at the x/y location relative to the panel you add the component to. Then you need to set the size of your component which would be the width/height.